# CreateWindowEx function fails but GetLastError() returns ERROR_SUCCESS

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, user-interface

I am trying to create a simple window with C/C++ using the native Windows message queue system (without .NET). I followed the MSDN tutorial and wrote some basic code that creates an empty window:

```
void main()
    {
    HINSTANCE hinst;
    HWND hwndMain;
    WNDCLASSEX wnd;
    MSG msg;

    hinst = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    memset( &wnd, 0, sizeof( wnd ) );
    wnd.cbSize = sizeof( wnd );
    wnd.lpszClassName = "MainWClass";
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = MainWProc;
    wnd.hInstance = hinst;
    int result = RegisterClassEx( &wnd );
    if( !result )
    {
        printf("RegisterClassEx error: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
    }

    hwndMain = CreateWindowEx
        (
        0, //extended styles
        wnd.lpszClassName, //class name
        "Main Window", //window name
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, //style tags
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //horizontal position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //vertical position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //width
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //height
        (HWND) NULL, //parent window
        (HMENU) NULL, //class menu
        (HINSTANCE) wnd.hInstance, //some HINSTANCE pointer
        NULL //Create Window Data?
        );

    if( !hwndMain )
    {
        printf("Oh shi- %d\n", GetLastError() );
    }
    ShowWindow( hwndMain, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
    UpdateWindow( hwndMain );
}
```

When I run/debug the program, CreateWindowEx returns 0 which means it failed. This triggers the error message "Oh shi- [error code]". The most confusing part is that the error message prints to console:

> Oh shi- 0

The error code returned by GetLastError() is 0, which is ERROR_SUCCESS!

I am at a total loss; what is happening? I am so confuse...

P.S.
I am using Visual C++ Express 2010 on Windows 7 32-bit. I have written a Windows Procedure elsewhere but it simply returns 0 for all cases. If, however, anyone wants to see it, I will be happy to show it.

**I have changed the Project Default character set of my Visual C++ project to "Not Set". I should not need to prefix L to my things.**

Edit: added wnd.hInstance = hinst;

Edit: removed the unnecessary (WNDPROC) cast

Edit: added error checking for RegisterClassEx

***It turns out that the problem was with Visual C++ Express (or at least not with the code itself). I copied the code to another project and it worked.***

Comment: I suppose you're intentionally not using the Visual Studio wizard/templates for educational purposes? Also, `void main()` is not valid C++.

Comment: Yes, I want to get a basic idea of how to use the native Windows message queue system before I start using wizards. The void return type of my main() function should have no bearing on the CreateWindowEx() function even if it is not supposedly valid.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use the wizard code without understanding it! :-) It's just that this boilerplate stuff is tricky enough to understand without *also* trying to type it all correctly.

Comment: @Joshua: in order to learn good, you need to stop using techniques that prevent learning. `void main` in one such. in absolute terms it's not that bad (it merely prevents the code from compiling with g++ and other compilers), but it is an **acceptance** of Microsoft lock-in coding patterns, and when you accept any of that, you're likely to accept more of it, and so on, and those coding patterns are really really bad (e.g., the error handling in the wizard generated code for window, Does Not Work). In particular, stop using those **C casts**. At once. They hide errors. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I mostly agree with what Alf says, except that when writing Win32 code, you are often forced to do non-portable, Microsoft-lock-in things. But `void main` is not one of them: the standard code doesn't declare the function that way. Neither are C-style casts. **Never** cast your window procedure function pointer to `WNDPROC`. That just hides errors. Everything should compile without a cast. As for Unicode, as I mentioned in a comment below, you *have* to compile the code as Unicode in order to get it to run on a modern version of Windows. That means either prefixing with `L` or macros.

Comment: @CodyGray, which modern versions of Windows are you talking about? Windows 7 at least still supports non-Unicode applications... All hell would break loose if half of the applications in use would stop working.

Comment: Not using Unicode for the character set is irrelevant if you are only programming for Windows, which I am. Windows doesn't break if you don't use Unicode.

Anyway, it turns out it was to do with Visual C++ Express...I created a new project, copied the code over and it worked. How do I close this question?

Comment: a really lazy solution to this is `if (msg == 36 || msg == 129 || msg == 130 || msg == 131) return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }` at the start of your WndProc. Good for troubleshooting.

Comment: An interesting way to fall into this issue is by trying to assume you get a chance to call `SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, (LONG_PTR)extradataptr` before any messages get sent to the window by having wndproc call GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0) and have the window get an access violation trying to read the nonexisting `cbWndExtra` data. This happened while I was trying to simulate Java awt/swing JFrame by passing a pointer to an unordered_map<UINT, WNDPROC> as cbWndExtra data; which would be ok if i checked if it was not a null pointer; I added the null check(with DefWindowProc) and everything worked.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
wnd.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) MainWProc;
```

We can't see the real reason you need to use the cast but it is very fishy.  Windows returns 0 from GetLastError() if it didn't see anything going wrong.  Which can happen if the window procedure is broken.  Like this one:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Windows sends the WM_NCCREATE message to ask for the window to be created.  If that message doesn't get processed then there will be no window.  And no error.  Fix:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Tweak as necessary to customize the window.  Just make sure that DefWindowProc() gets called for every message that you don't want to handle yourself.  And keep Petzold close at hand to avoid the simple mistakes.  And lose the cast.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I removed the WNDPROC cast but the problem persisted. Turns out the problem was with Visual C++ (or at least not with the code) since it worked after I copied the code to another project.

P.S. When I said the Window Procedure returns 0 for all cases, I did not mean that it merely has one line of return 0; code. I had a valid Window Procedure case-switch that returns DefWndowProc by default. Thank you!

Comment: Great this helped a lot!  Do you know if the default window procedure will terminate the message loop when closed via the 'x'?  My message loop only translates and dispatches messages, so my assumption is that it would exit when the PostQuitMessage is sent.  I don't know if this is sent when the 'x' is clicked (or other methods such as Alt+F4).

Comment: @NickMiller `PostQuitMessage` is _not_ called when your window is X'd out. You'll receive a `WM_CLOSE` message for the window, and you'll need to call `PostQuitMessage` in that handler.

Comment: WM_DESTROY is best.  No more main window => quit program.

Answer (score 2):

All modern versions of Windows use Unicode internally, and by default, Visual Studio projects #define `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE`, which causes your application to link to the Unicode versions of the Windows headers.

When you're compiling an application as Unicode, however, the character (and thus "string") types are different. Instead of `char`, they're now `wchar_t`. That means that you have to explicitly declare your string literals as long strings by prefixing them with an `L`.

Alternatively, the Windows headers hide all of this behind macros, but it's no longer necessary because Windows has been Unicode for a long time and that's very unlikely to change.

Beyond that, you're missing several things in your initialization of the `WNDCLASSEX` structure, like the `hInstance` member. These things all have to be set perfectly, or things will fail. As well, the `RegisterClass(Ex)` and `CreateWindow(Ex)` functions must be passed the *exact same string* values corresponding to the name of the window class, otherwise they will assume you're talking about two different things. Typos are not forgiven!

I highly recommend that you use the Visual Studio wizards to create a blank (but working!) project template.

The correct boilerplate code goes something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Define these here to minimize typos, or preferably, load them from a
// resource file at the top of the main function
#define MYCLASSNAME    TEXT("MainWndClass")
#define MYWINDOWNAME   TEXT("Main Window")

// Global variable to keep track of your hInstance
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   // If you don't process any of the messages yourself, you
   // must pass them to DefWindowProc for default handling.
   return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{     
    // Save the instance handle in a global variable.
    g_hInstance = hInstance;

    // Register your window class.
    // (A full-featured app will probably want to set additional members.)
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = {0};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = MYCLASSNAME;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create your main window.
    HWND hwndMain = CreateWindowEx(0, MYCLASSNAME, MYWINDOWNAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                   CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,
                                   hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hwndMain)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Call to CreateWindowEx failed!"), NULL, MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    // Show your main window.
    ShowWindow(hwndMain, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwndMain);

    // Run the main message loop.
    BOOL bRetVal;
    MSG msg;
    while ((bRetVal = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRetVal == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Error encountered in message loop!"), NULL, MB_OK);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the Project Default character set to "Not Set". I also do not own a non-Express version of Visual Studio which is why I cannot use wizards =(

I have got a dispatch message loop elsewhere but I have not included it because it would not work anyway since CreateWindowEx is not succeeding in the first place.

Comment: You don't want "Not Set". You want Unicode; it's the default. All versions of Windows NT are natively Unicode. The last version of Windows that used non-Unicode ("ANSI") applications was Windows 98. I doubt you're running that still. Things will not work unless you compile as Unicode. If you don't like all the `TEXT()` macros, etc. you can just prefix string literals with an `L`. Fair enough about Express, though. The sample code I posted should work out of the box.

Comment: @CodyGray, the last version of Windows that didn't natively support Unicode was Windows ME. Anyway, all systems based on Windows 2000 support both Unicode and non-Unicode applications.

Answer (score -1):

In my case i had to handle WNC_NCCREATE manually. DefWindowProc returned zero for WNC_NCCREATE, i fixed that with:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WNC_NCCREATE) 
        return true;
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try initializing all of the members/properties of the window class. In other words, set the remaining members. For example:

```
winclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc1;
winclass.hInstance = hInstance;
winclass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(250,250,250));
winclass.lpszClassName = "mwClass";
winclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
winclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
winclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
winclass.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
winclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
winclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
```

Just change the class name as needed.

Comment: The code in question already zero-initializes the `WNDCLASSEX` structure, so doing it all over again is rather pointless. Besides, if window class registration failed, the call to `CreateWindowEx` would fail, but have `GetLastError` return a non-zero value. The problem this proposed answer attempts to fix is not the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: By the way, WNDCLASSEX wcex = {0} does not initialize all of the memory occupied by the object. I also had this problem and when I initialized all of the members of the window class, the window appeared.

Comment: The OP is calling `memset`. Regardless, `WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {0};` zero-initializes ALL memory. It's a hard language rule, and I don't know of a single compiler that fails this. Though zero-initialization isn't sufficient for the `EX` version; you'll also need to properly set its `cbSize` member (which this proposed answer doesn't). Some contributions are best just deleted. This is one of those.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.

In my case its just that i used visual sutdio without admin rights. 
And i discovered that in this case i cant debug my application. 
In debug mode without admin right, CreateWindowEx return null with error code result to 0 like you.
But if you go to your build directory you can use your app (not in debug mode). 
So if this the case fro you too, just start visula studio with admin right and its done.

I think there is almost a way to use visual studio debug mode with admin right without start visual stuido with admin password each time. i dont know how to do that, but i think it may be possible.